# Findstr with user input for batch file

Tags: batch-file, user-input, findstr

I was wondering if it is possible to create a batch file that asks the user for input such as a "promocode" and searches for the "promocode" the user just input. If they are equal then I would want to open a file such as a word file, excel or sql.  I want to be able to do this because for every different code a different file will need to be opened for coworkers. If I had a file that could be searched to see if the promocode is there then I will not need to keep on adding code for a new promocode they can just add the promocode to the text file.
If this code cannot be done please let me know.

```
@echo off
SET /P promocode="Type a promocode please:"
for %%d in (\path\ReadThisFileTest.txt) do (
if findstr "MCD758" == %promocode% goto :MCD758

:MCD758
start \path\test.docx
```

I have been trying a whole lot of things and here is one example. I don't know if you can even do this or if it is in the right order.

EDIT 
What is in the ReadThisFileTest.txt is the promocodes:
MCD758
MCD555
MCD957.  There are more than just those three but they are each on their own line in the text file.  Also each has 3 letters followed by 3 numbers, as shown.

Comment: You cannot use `findstr` within an `if` statement. Anyway, I don't really get what the question is. Does `\path\ReadThisFileTest.txt` contain a list of "promocodes"? How to know which file/program to start depending on the code?

Comment: Edit the post and add one line from `ReadThisFileTest.txt` as an example.

Comment: Yes that file with the path contains a list of "promocodes".  And right now it would open that test doc if it worked. I can get it to work with a nested if and open different files based on the promocode but as I said I would prefer not to have to keep editing the code every time another promocode needs to be added.  So what I am looking for is a way to read a file with promocodes in it and if it is equal to what the user typed then open a file based the promocode the user typed.

Comment: In your code, the closing parenthesis for the `for` body is missing. Moreover, you need to state `exit /B` after it because otherwise execution will always continue at `:MCD758`, even if no match has been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Edited to reflect new information)*

If the promocodes are identical to the prefix of the filenames you want to open, you can do:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P promocode="Type a promocode please: "
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G IN ( "\path\ReadThisFileTest.txt" ) DO (
    IF "%promocode%" == "%%G" (
        START CMD /C "path\%%G.docx"
        EXIT
    )
)
ECHO No matching code found.
```

Comment: So for this method it searches the file to look for what the user inputted but you then the user needs to have the path for the file they need to open correct?

Comment: @vince: Yes, I got the impression that you have an unrelated filename for every promocode. If the filename is related, i.e. for `MCD758` you want `path\MCD758.docx` to be opened, it gets even easier. Is that the case?

Comment: I believe that is the case. For a certain promocode it would have a certain filename that would need to be opened. So MCD758 would open say path\MCD758.docx and MCD555 would open path\MCD555.docx

Comment: Edited, this should solve your problem. I've added a `CMD /C` after the `START` since that seems to be necessary on some machines (the one I'm sitting at now vs. the one I sat before when first answering).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been at this for the last couple days and probably would've never figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible way is to extend the promocode file `\path\ReadThisFileTest.txt` to contain two (whitespace-separated) columns, like this:

```
MCD758  \path\test.docx
MCD759  \path\to\another\file.xlsx
```

So the file names are no longer bound to the promocodes, and you could give even different paths and/or file extensions.

The batch code would then look like:

```
@echo off
set /P promocode="Type a promocode please: "
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%F in ("\path\ReadThisFileTest.txt") do (
    if "%promocode%"=="%%F" (
        start %%~G
        exit /B
    )
)
echo The promocode you entered is not valid.
```

If you want the promocodes to be checked in a case-insensitive manner, you need to replace `if "%promocode%"=="%%F"` by `if /I "%promocode%"=="%%F"`.